# How to make this awk script simple and use in gnuscript in loop form

Tags: gnuplot

I am attempting to plot a multicolum file using gnuplot script.
I am doing it like

```
plot "100.dat" u ($1-CONS):($2*$3)  w l lt 4 , 
"200.dat" u ($1-CONS):($2*$3)  w l lt 2 , 
"300.dat" u ($1-CONS):($2*$3)  w l lt 1
```

where CONS is my variable defined at the top of file.

My set xrange is [-0.2:0.2] while data in the scale is beyond this scale.

What I want to capture is (in loop form for multiple files):
maximum value  of above three plots in negative and positive both sides and corresponding value of column 1 in my xrange for both the maximum.

in a shell script I can do it easily but I am facing problem in defining in my gnuscript
my shell script is below

```
for i in 100.0000 200.0000 200.0000
do
    grep $i data.dat > $i.dat



awk '{print ($1-CONS), ($2*$3)}' $i.dat | awk '{ if($1 <= 0.2 && $1 >= 0.0) { print }}' > $i.p2.dat ; awk 'BEGIN {min=1000000; max=0;}; { if($2<min && $2 != "") min = $2; if($2>max && $2 != "") max = $2; } END {print min, max}' $i.p2.dat  | awk '{print $2}' > $i.p2Max.dat ;  PMAX=$(cat $i.p2Max.dat) ; grep "$PMAX"  $i.p2.dat  | tail -n 1 >> MAX.dat



awk '{print ($1-CONS), ($2*$3)}' $i.dat | awk '{ if($1 <= 0.0 && $1 >= -0.2) { print }}' > $i.mi.dat ; awk 'BEGIN {min=1000000; max=0;}; { if($2<min && $2 != "") min = $2; if($2>max && $2 != "") max = $2; } END {print min, max}' $i.mi.dat  | awk '{print $2}' > $i.mi_Max.dat ;  N_MAX=$(cat $i.mi_Max.dat) ; grep "$N_MAX"  $i.mi.dat  | tail -n 1 >> MAX.dat
done
```

I am looking for a simple script that can be used in the gnuplot script in loop form so that if I have multiple data file and I need to grep the maximum of a colum two (on both the sides of the zero) then it store the maximum value  of column two wrt  corresponding value of column 1 separately for negative and positive scale.

I would love to see if this can be done using a loop so that I do not need to write all the lines repetitively.

Comment: so, do you want the minima and maxima of `($2*$3)` and the corresponding `($1-CON)` values for each of the 3 files? Or one minimum and maximum value for all the 3 files?

Comment: ($2*$3) will be having some peaks below zero (in the range -0.2:0.0) and above zero (in the range 0.0:0.2). I want that peak value (what I call it maximum of $2*$3) and corresponding value of  $1. The corresponding value $1 should  be in variable form also so that I will grep this value in remaining part of the script.  So ideally the output  should looks like  if I do cat the output file     -0.05    1.165e+14  and in next row    0.06   1.236e+13, where $1 in the output file will represent the value at x-axis and $2 corresponding maximum value. and there rows will repeat times the loop values

Comment: Please notice here that $1 in the output file will be negative for the negative scale (-0.2:0.0) so also suggest how to grep this negative variable value.

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is a bit confusing to me. My understanding is the following: loop through several files and extract the maxima in the xranges [-0.2:0] and [0:0.2], 
respectively.

**Test data:**

`100.dat`

```
-0.17 0.447 0.287
-0.13 0.353 0.936
-0.09 0.476 0.309
-0.05 0.504 0.220
-0.01 0.340 0.564
0.03 0.096 0.947
0.07 0.564 0.885
0.11 0.312 0.957
0.15 0.058 0.347
0.19 0.016 0.923
0.23 0.835 0.461
```

`200.dat`

```
-0.17 0.608 0.875
-0.13 0.266 0.805
-0.09 0.948 0.696
-0.05 0.513 0.800
-0.01 0.736 0.392
0.03 0.318 0.312
0.07 0.708 0.534
0.11 0.246 0.975
0.15 0.198 0.914
0.19 0.174 0.318
0.23 0.727 0.341
```

`300.dat`

```
-0.17 0.527 0.658
-0.13 0.166 0.340
-0.09 0.695 0.031
-0.05 0.623 0.542
-0.01 0.996 0.674
0.03 0.816 0.365
0.07 0.286 0.433
0.11 0.069 0.381
0.15 0.719 0.621
0.19 0.516 0.701
0.23 0.248 0.659
```

**Code:**

```
### loop of files and extracting values
reset session

FILES = "100.dat 200.dat 300.dat"
Count = words(FILES)
CONS = 0.03

# get maxima
array NegMaxX[Count]
array NegMaxY[Count]
array PosMaxX[Count]
array PosMaxY[Count]
do for [i=1:Count] {
    stats [-0.2:0] word(FILES,i) u ($1-CONS):($2*$3) nooutput
    NegMaxX[i] = STATS_pos_max_y
    NegMaxY[i] = STATS_max_y
    stats [0:0.2] word(FILES,i) u ($1-CONS):($2*$3) nooutput
    PosMaxX[i] = STATS_pos_max_y
    PosMaxY[i] = STATS_max_y
}

set xrange[-0.2:0.2]
# set labels
do for [i=1:Count] {
    set label i*2-1 at NegMaxX[i], NegMaxY[i] sprintf("%.3f/%.3f",NegMaxX[i],NegMaxY[i])
    set label i*2 at PosMaxX[i], PosMaxY[i] sprintf("%.3f/%.3f",PosMaxX[i],PosMaxY[i])
}

plot for [i=1:Count] word(FILES,i) u ($1-CONS):($2*$3) w l lt i ti word(FILES,i), \
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]